# Does the conservative two phase locking protocol produce cascadeless schedules?

Tags: concurrency, database-theory

Let us consider the following schedule :

\begin{array}{lcr}
\mbox{$T_1$} & \mbox{$T_2$}\\
\\
\mbox{lock-exclusive(a)}  \\
\mbox{lock-exclusive(b)}  \\
\mbox{read(a)} \\
\mbox{a=a+50} \\
\mbox{write(a)} \\
\mbox{unlock(a)} \\
\mbox{} & \mbox{lock-exclusive(a)}\\
\mbox{} & \mbox{read(a)}\\
\mbox{} & \mbox{a=a+50}\\
\mbox{} & \mbox{write(a)}\\
\mbox{} & \mbox{unlock(a)}\\
\mbox{read(b)} \\
\mbox{b=b+100} \\
\mbox{write(b)} \\
\mbox{unlock(b)} \\ \end{array}

Since in the schedule the lock on $a$ is released, it is possible for the transaction $T_2$ to acquire the lock on $a$. Now the transaction $T_2$ reads the value of $a$ which was written by transaction $T_1$. This implies that if the transaction $T_1$ aborts, the transaction $T_2$ must be aborted for consistency purposes. Does it mean that even though a conservative two phase protocol is used, the schedules may not necesssarily be cascadeless?

Comment: Database and concurrency experts, can you propose meaningful tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the **conservative 2PL** does not garantuee cascadelessness. Requesting all locks at the beginning of the transaction is used to prevent deadlocks.

If you want to prevent cascading rollbacks, you need to have a look at how the locks are released. There are two versions of the 2PL-Protocol that garantuee cascadeless schedules: the **strong 2PL** and the **rigorous 2PL**, which is even stricter.

Schedules that satisfy the strong 2PL may release read-locks at any time and all write-lock at the end of the transaction. Schedules that satisfy the rigorous 2PL may only release all locks at the end of the transaction.

Lets have a look at what happens to your schedule if you use the conservative and rigorous (or strong) 2PL.

\begin{array}{lcr}
\mbox{$T_1$} & \mbox{$T_2$}\\
\\
\mbox{lock-exclusive(a)}  \\
\mbox{lock-exclusive(b)}  \\
\mbox{read(a)} \\
\mbox{a=a+50} \\
\mbox{write(a)} \\
\mbox{read(b)} \\
\mbox{b=b+100} \\
\mbox{write(b)} \\
\mbox{unlock(a)} \\
\mbox{unlock(b)} \\ 
\mbox{} & \mbox{lock-exclusive(a)}\\
\mbox{} & \mbox{read(a)}\\
\mbox{} & \mbox{a=a+50}\\
\mbox{} & \mbox{write(a)}\\
\mbox{} & \mbox{unlock(a)}\\
\end{array}

Because $T_1$ is not allowed to do $\mbox{unlock(a)}$, $T_2$ can not request the lock and therefore can not start. $T_1$ continues until the end and releases its lock. Now $T_2$ can start.

You can also see here that a conservative, rigorous 2PL leads to a serial execution of Transactions that access the same variables.

Comment: does C2PL guarantee recoverability?